# Access properties in anonymous type collection - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, drop-down-menu, anonymous-types

In the source code below, I am selecting a subset of properties from the `users` collection and I need to bind it to a drop down list:

```
var locationDepts = (from u in users select new { u.RcNumber, u.RcName }).Distinct().ToList();

if(!locationDepts.Count.Equals(0))
{
    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataSource = locationDepts;
    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataValueField = "RcNumber";

    //Want to format display test "RCNumber - RcName"
    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataTextField = string.Format("{0} - {1}", locationDepts.RcNumber, locationDepts.RcName);

    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataBind();
}
```

I want to format the list item display text as a combination of the anonymous type RcNumber and RcName.  How do I access the properties of the anonymous type to indicate the format the text of the drop down list items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new property in the data-source called "Combined"

```
var locationDepts = (from u in users 
                    select new 
                    { 
                        u.RcNumber, 
                        Combined = u.RcNumber + " - " + u.RcName
                    }).Distinct().ToList();

if(locationDepts.Count > 0)
{
    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataSource = locationDepts;
    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataValueField = "RcNumber";
    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataTextField = "Combined";
    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far - DataTextField is basically a mapping to an object's property name, so you can't create a "computed" text field value like you did with the string.format - it would instead look for a property name called "RcNumber - RcName".

Answer (score 4):

I would just change the anonymous type to include the already-formatted value:

```
var locationDepts = (from u in users select new { u.RcNumber, RcName = String.Format("{0} - {1}", u.RcNumber, u.RcName) }).Distinct().ToList();

if(!locationDepts.Count.Equals(0))
{
    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataSource = locationDepts;
    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataValueField = "RcNumber";

    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataTextField = "RcName";

    ddlRCListPerBuilding.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: +1: I slightly prefer your String.Format(...) to the concatenation in the other answer by @Magnus

Comment: @MikeGoodwin It is still gonna concatenate them (with String.Format) but with a little more code and little slower.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a view model

```
public class RcFields
{
    public int RcNumber { get; set; }
    public string RcName { get; set; } 
}

List<RcFields> locationDepts = (from u in users 
                                select new RcFields 
                                { 
                                   u.RcNumber, 
                                   u.RcName 
                                })
                                .Distinct()
                                .ToList();
```

then

```
 ... locationDepts.RcName ..
```